# Assigning multidimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I'm trying to assign multidimensional array to unitilized array in struct like this:

```
typedef struct TestStruct
{
    int matrix[10][10];

} TestStruct;

TestStruct *Init(void)
{
    TestStruct *test = malloc(sizeof(TestStruct));

    test->matrix = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

    return test;
}
```

I got next error:

```
test.c:14:17: error: expected expression before '{' token
  test->matrix = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
```

What is the best way in C to assign matrix?

Comment: Arrays cannot be assigned in C. They can be initialised, but this can *only* be done on definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot initialize the matrix this way.  In C99, you can do this instead:

```
*test = (TestStruct){{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}};
```

Before C99, you would use a local structure:

```
TestStruct *Init(void) {
    static TestStruct init_value = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}};

    TestStruct *test = malloc(sizeof(TestStruct));

    if (test)
        *test = init_value;

    return test;
}
```

Note that structure assignent `*test = init_value;` is substantially equivalent to using `memcpy(test, &init_value, sizeof(*test));` or a nested loop where you copy the individual elements of `test->matrix`.

You can also clone an existing matrix this way:

```
TestStruct *Clone(const TestStruct *mat) {

    TestStruct *test = malloc(sizeof(TestStruct));

    if (test)
        *test = *mat;

    return test;
}
```

Comment: But I want initialize matrix in Init() function, is there a way to do it via pointers?

Comment: @JacobLutin: the various methods described above **do** initialize the matrix.  What do you mean by *is there a way to do it via pointers?*